# Is ones complement distributive?

Tags: binary

I know it's associative and commutative:

That is,

```
(~x1 + ~x2) + ~x3 = ~x1 + (~x2 + ~x3)
```

and

```
~x1 + ~x2 = ~x2 + ~x1
```

However, for the cases I tried, it doesn't seem to be distributive, i.e,

```
~x1 + ~x2 != ~(x1 + x2)
```

Is this true?  Is there a proof?

I have C code as follows:

```
int n1 = 5;
int n2 = 3;
result = ~n1 + ~n2 == ~(n1 + n2);

int calc = ~n1;  
int calc0 = ~n2;  
int calc1 = ~n1 + ~n2;  
int calc2 = ~(n1 + n2);

printf("(Part B: n1 is %d, n2 is %d\n", n1, n2);
printf("Part B: (calc is: %d and calc0 is: %d\n", calc, calc0); 
printf("Part B: (calc1 is: %d and calc2 is: %d\n", calc1, calc2);
printf("Part B: (~%d + ~%d) == ~(%d + %d) evaluates to %d\n", n1, n2, n1, n2, result);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Part B: (n1 is 5, n2 is 3
Part B: (calc is: -6 and calc0 is: -4
Part B: (calc1 is: -10 and calc2 is: -9
Part B: (~5 + ~3) == ~(5 + 3) evaluates to 0
```

Comment: This doesn't look like distributive rule. And distribute of what over what?

Comment: Then perhaps distributive is not the right word?  I was just wondering if the inequality could be proven.  That is, is the sum of ones' complement of 2 numbers equal to the ones complement of the sum?

Comment: What does `+` mean? Is it OR, or is it ADD?

Comment: My apologies, I'm adding 2 binary numbers.

Comment: Then you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[I know this is really old, but I had the same question, and since the top answers were contradictory...]

The one's compliment is indeed distributive over addition.  The problem in your code (and Kaganar's kind but incorrect answer) is that you are dropping the carry bits -- you can do that in two-s compliment, but not in one's compliment.

Whatever you use to store the sum needs more memory space than what you are summing so that you don't drop your carry bits.  Then fold the carry bits back into the number of bits you are using to store your operands to get the proper sum.  This is called an "end-around carry" in one's compliment arithmetic.

From Wikipedia article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Ones'_complement ):

> To add two numbers represented in this system, one does a conventional binary addition, but it is then necessary to do an end-around carry: that is, add any resulting carry back into the resulting sum. To see why this is necessary, consider the following example showing the case of the addition of −1 (11111110) to +2 (00000010):

```
      binary    decimal
    11111110     –1
 +  00000010     +2
 ───────────     ──
  1 00000000      0   ← Not the correct answer
           1     +1   ← Add carry
 ───────────     ──
    00000001      1   ← Correct answer
```

> In the previous example, the first binary addition gives 00000000, which is incorrect. The correct result (00000001) only appears when the carry is added back in.

I changed your code a bit to make it easier to do the math myself for a sanity check and tested.  It may require a bit more thought using signed integer datatypes or to account for end-around borrowing instead of carrying.  I didn't go that far since my application is all about checksums (i.e. unsigned, and addition only).

```
unsigned short n1 = 5;  //using 16-bit unsigned integers
unsigned short n2 = 3;

unsigned long oc_added = (unsigned short)~n1 + (unsigned short)~n2; //32bit
/*  Fold the carry bits into 16 bits */
while (oc_added >> 16)
    oc_added = (oc_added & 0xffff) + (oc_added >> 16);

unsigned long oc_sum = ~(n1 + n2);  //oc_sum has 32 bits (room for carry) 
/*  Fold the carry bits into 16 bits */
while (oc_sum >> 16)
    oc_sum = (oc_sum & 0xffff) + (oc_sum >> 16);

int result = oc_added == oc_sum;

unsigned short calc = ~n1;
unsigned short calc0 = ~n2;
unsigned short calc1 = ~n1 + ~n2;  //loses a carry bit
unsigned short calc2 = ~(n1 + n2);

printf("(Part B: n1 is %d, n2 is %d\n", n1, n2);
printf("Part B: (calc is: %d and calc0 is: %d\n", calc, calc0);
printf("Part B: (calc1 is: %d and calc2 is: %d\n", calc1, calc2);
printf("Part B: (~%d + ~%d) == ~(%d + %d) evaluates to %d\n", n1, n2, n1, n2, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Wikiepdia article on [Ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement). Addition in one's complement has end-carry around where you must add the overflow bit to the lowest bit.

Since `~` (NOT) is equivalent to `-` (NEGATE) in ones' complement, we can re-write it as:

```
-x1 + -x2 = -(x1 + x2)
```

which is correct.

Comment: But this equality doesn't hold. I ran a C program and I get false for every number I've tried.  I read somewhere that ones complement was not distributive, but how to prove this?

Comment: @user1317750: At least Intel uses 2's complement in the representation of negative numbers (not sure about others), so of course it is wrong. I don't know distributive rule of what operator over what operator, so I cannot say anything here.

Comment: If x and y are represented as 32 bit integers, and if you take the ones complement of x and the ones complement of y, and add them together, do you get the same result as adding x and y, getting z, and taking the ones complement of z.  By ones complement, I just mean flipping the bits.

Comment: @user1317750: They should always be equal, **if you do the addition correctly**. If you can find any counter example, try to post it here (I don't think there will be any, though).

Comment: @user1317750: The computer uses twos' complement and addition in twos' complement is different from ones' complement.

Answer (score 0):

One's compliment is used to represent negative and positive numbers in fixed-width registers. To distribute over addition the following must apply: `~a + ~b` = `~(a + b)`. The OP states `+` represents adding 'two binary numbers'. This itself is vague, however if we take it to mean adding unsigned binary numbers, then no, one's compliment is not distributive.

Note that there are two zeroes in one's compliment: all bits are ones or all bits are zeroes.

Check to see that `~0 + ~0 !=  ~(0 + 0)`:
`~0` is zero. However, `~0` is represented by all ones. Adding it to itself is doubling it -- the same as a left shift -- and thus introduces a zero in the right hand digit. But that is no longer one of the two zeroes.

However, `0` is zero, and `0 + 0` is also zero, and thus so is `~(0 + 0)`. But the left side isn't zero, so to distribution does not hold.

**On the other hand**... Consider two's compliment: flip all bits and add one. If care is taken to treat negatives in one's compliment specially, then that version of 'binary addition' is similar to two's compliment and is distributive as you end up with a familiar [quotient ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29#Quotient_ring) just like in two's compliment.

The aforementioned [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) has more details on handling addition to allow for expected arithmetic behavior.

Answer (score -1):

From [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
 ~(x1 + x2) = ~x1 * ~x2
```

Comment: De Morgan's laws are for logical AND, OR, and NOT -- not for addition, multiplication, and bitwise negation.